# how to set default language to browser for all URLs opened?

Tags: python-2.7, url, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://...")
```

Python script: some URLs opened in English, some in Russian - which cause assertion problems

How to set all to English?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined a preferred language in your browser settings?

Comment: Yes, and my Chrome accept and use it.
But default browser for selenium use his own settings and clear all the changes on every new circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing 'Display language' from default(Russian) to English(USA)

```
Start > Control panel > Region and Language > 
Keyboards and Laguages > Display Language > Choose a display language in dropdown.
```